# .net wpf publish single file from console create large file (from UI not)

Tags: .net

when i publish my project from visual studio menu (project->publish) it create only few files and they are not large - like it not creating portable version, because i have set publish profile like below:

[image]

when i had target runtime = portable it was creating large file (i think it contained runtine env)

And this is cool but i have to be able to do this same on pipeline so i try to invoke same from console using:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --framework net6.0-windows --configuration Release
```

but it create large file > 140mb (prolably with runtime env)
tried also with -use-current-runtime parameter (false and true)

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --framework net6.0-windows --configuration Release --use-current-runtime false
```

but still got really large file
[image]

How invoke deployment command equally to i do it from visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

omg  just added

```
--self-contained false
```

and works like a charm
[image]